# Select rows from datatable with distinct column values

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that has duplicate ID's.

```
1 data moredata  4354
1 data moredata  4354
2 data moredaaata  4asdfdsa4
3 dasata edaaata  42342fdsa4
2 data moredaaata  4asdfdsa4
```

I want to get a datatable from that table with just row for each of the first column value like this: (does not need to be in order)

```
1 data moredata  4354
2 data moredaaata  4asdfdsa4
3 dasata edaaata  42342fdsa4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have any control over the query that returns the data?  I would think that `SELECT DISTINCT` on whatever query you are using would make more sense.

Comment: @CSharpDev, Distinct will work on all the columns, for the sample data it will work, but it may fail on `1 data moredata 5555`, in that case it will return two rows with ID 1

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It's not comping from SQL, and I do not have control over the results I get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use LINQ to query the datatable. Use group by on `ID` field and select `First` from the resultset. Something like..

```
var query = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group t by t.Field<int>("ID") into g
            select g.First();
```

Comment: We need a LINQFTW tag on answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> tableColumns = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn column in currentTable.Columns)
    tableColumns.Add(column.ColumnName);
DataTable result = currentTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, tableColumns.ToArray());
```

Comment: I think this is more likely what he was looking.  Good use of generic combinations which should allow any user to specify the arrays as needed.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column 2
FROM Table1
WHERE ......